# SQL Server : How to use XPATH in select query

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

I have a table in SQL Server which has a column with XML data type. For example, one value looks like

```
<doc>

<q></q>

<p1>
    <p2 dd="ert" ji="pp">

        <p3>1</p3>
        <p3>2</p3>
        <p3>XYZ</p3>
        <p3>3</p3>

     </p2>

     <p2 dd="ert" ji="pp">

        <p3>4</p3>
        <p3>5</p3>
        <p3>ABC</p3>
        <p3>6</p3>

     </p2>

</p1>
<r></r>
<p1>
    <p2 dd="ert" ji="pp">

        <p3>7</p3>
        <p3>8</p3>
        <p3>ABC</p3>
        <p3>9</p3>

     </p2>

     <p2 dd="ert" ji="pp">

        <p3>10</p3>
        <p3>11</p3>
        <p3>XYZ</p3>
        <p3>12</p3>

     </p2>

</p1>
</doc>
```

now, i would want to execute the following xpath

```
./doc//p1/p2/p3[contains(text(),'ABC') or contains(text(),'XYZ')]/preceding-sibling::p3
```

so the result is

```
1 2 4 5 7 8 10 11
```

so i want to select all `<p3>` nodes that are siblings of the `<p3>` nodes with text ABC or XYZ. Also, these `<p3>` nodes must be within `<p2>` nodes that are themselves within `<p1>` nodes. As of now, i just select the column as it is and then use the xpath in python to get the nodes. Is there a way to get the required nodes using the SQL select query?

**EDIT**

Note that it would suffice even if i got

```
<p3>1</p3>
        <p3>2</p3>
<p3>4</p3>
        <p3>5</p3>
<p3>7</p3>
        <p3>8</p3>
<p3>10</p3>
        <p3>11</p3>
```

because then i can easily use an XML parser to get the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some limitations to be considered in the SQL Server's XPath/XQuery, i.e neither `following-sibling` nor `preceding-sibling` are supported. As an alternative, you can use `>>` or `<<` operator to compare sibling elements position. See the demo below.

**Input XML in an XML variable :**

```
declare @xml XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc> 
  <q/>  
  <p1> 
    <p2 dd="ert" ji="pp"> 
      <p3>1</p3>  
      <p3>2</p3>  
      <p3>XYZ</p3>  
      <p3>3</p3> 
    </p2>  
    <p2 dd="ert" ji="pp"> 
      <p3>4</p3>  
      <p3>5</p3>  
      <p3>ABC</p3>  
      <p3>6</p3> 
    </p2> 
  </p1>  
  <r/>  
  <p1> 
    <p2 dd="ert" ji="pp"> 
      <p3>7</p3>  
      <p3>8</p3>  
      <p3>ABC</p3>  
      <p3>9</p3> 
    </p2>  
    <p2 dd="ert" ji="pp"> 
      <p3>10</p3>  
      <p3>11</p3>  
      <p3>XYZ</p3>  
      <p3>12</p3> 
    </p2> 
  </p1> 
</doc>'
```

**Query :**

```
SELECT @xml.query('
/doc/p1/p2/p3[. << ../p3[contains(.,"ABC") or contains(.,"XYZ")][last()]]
')
```

**output :** (tested in SQL Server 2008R2)

```
<p3>1</p3>
<p3>2</p3>
<p3>4</p3>
<p3>5</p3>
<p3>7</p3>
<p3>8</p3>
<p3>10</p3>
<p3>11</p3>
```

Comment: Yes, XML &XPath are case sensitive

Comment: thanks man! just a follow up, can i make the xpath query optional? meaning if there is a <p2> which does not have either <p3>ABC</p3> or <p3>XYZ</p3>, then i still want all of the <p3>s in that <p2>

Answer (score 1):

Think from another perspective. Start the XPath expression with the `p3` elements you are actually interested in. Use the following expression:

```
/doc/p1/p2/p3[following-sibling::p3 = 'ABC' or following-sibling::p3 = 'XYZ']
```

or even

```
/doc/p1/p2/p3[following-sibling::p3[. = 'ABC' or . = 'XYZ']]
```

which will retrieve (individual results separated by `---------`):

```
<p3>1</p3>
-----------------------
<p3>2</p3>
-----------------------
<p3>4</p3>
-----------------------
<p3>5</p3>
-----------------------
<p3>7</p3>
-----------------------
<p3>8</p3>
-----------------------
<p3>10</p3>
-----------------------
<p3>11</p3>
```

Comment: thanks, but how do i specify this in the select query? lets say the xml data is in col1. how can i do select col1 from table?

Comment: @AbtPst If the XPath expression is already clear to you, you should tag the question with `sql` (I guess) and show the query you have right now. Also, I would imagine selecting a column is easy in SQL?

Comment: i dont have the query, i can just do select col1 from table. i dont know how to specify the xpath when i am selecting col1